# Mouse not working in Linux on a computer, but works fine on other Linux Machines

Tags: usb, mouse

I'm trying to install ubuntu linux on one of my computers, but my mouse does not respond, although my USB keyboard does. I use an MSI 970 Gaming motherboard, if that may help at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try a different mouse? What kind of mouse is this? Are you sure the USB port you're plugging it into is good?

Comment: I did try a different mouse, and a different USB port. I know the usb port is good because I use it on my windows partition. It is the mouse bundled in the Cooler Master Devastator bundle.

Comment: Did the different mouse work? Check the BIOS, see if there's a "legacy mouse" setting of some kind.